# How to specify different Css for different Mobiles (BB, Iphone, Nexus... )

Tags: asp.net, html, mobile, css, jquery-mobile

I am currently developing a mobile web application in `ASP.net` and `jQuery` + `jQm`  that will be used on handheld devices. I want to be able to specify a theme for `Blackberry`, one for `Google Nexus` and one for `IPhone`, and not just this ones.

Is there any way I could specify a theme for each one in CSS3? 
Can you please point out what to do in this case. 
Also I want that when I rotate screen to keep the design in place for all the devices above.

I am currently experimenting with this :

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) and (max-width: 819px)
```

but I am open for other approaches also.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either check the browser user agent by using javascript or through server-side code.

[I recommend this mobile phone detector](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Not in CSS but using JS you can tap into the `navigator.useragent` property and load the corresponding stylesheet dynamically for each platform.

Comment: Both answers: yours and Dandroid are useful. But I cannot give you both accepted answer.